# Twitter t.co links is not fetching images

Tags: html

t.co of twitter is not fetching images. After redirecting to another link  it is unable to fetch the images.
my code is:

```
<pre>
  <img class="imgmyclass" src="https://t.co/onj4Gps4rQ">
</pre>
```

please help.
Thanks

Comment: <div><img class="imgcls" src="https://t.co/onj4Gps4rQ">

Comment: Because that's not a valid image. Try linking to https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CZ4p4TCUAAEQKJt.jpg instead.

Answer (score 0):

Because the url does not point to an image.

As far as the image in the link you are trying to extract the image from is concerned, use this:

```
<img class="imgmyclass" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CZ4p4TCUAAEQKJt.jpg">
```

Where src tag is used to point to an image, not the url of a page which contains a post and an image associated with it.

If you want to extract the image url, open the html page, right click on the image and hit `copy link address`. Do not forget to Give proper credits to the owner of the image.

Comment: Actually twitter api is returning this shorthand url and for some scenarios it is showing images with shorthand url.